# MacOS iptables equivalent

Tags: docker, macos, network-programming, firewall, iptables

I recently switched from Linux to Mac.

My symfony application runs in a docker-compose setup
and has a socks5 proxy, I want to tunnel an ssh connection to.
`SYMFONY_APP_PROXY=socks5h://172.17.0.1:8086`

So previously I was using the following commands:

- `docker inspect symfony_app | grep IPAddress | awk '{print $2}'`
- `ip route get 172.18.0.0 | awk '{print $4}'`
- `sudo iptables -I INPUT 1 -i <docker-container-id> -j ACCEPT`
- `ssh -D 172.17.0.1:8086 -v davchs@some.example.com`

So basically, I think I just need the macOS equivalent for that iptables command to make it work. I struggle the last day to figure out how I could do it on macOS.

I really appreciate any help, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your are looking for pfctl: [pfctl openbsd](https://www.openbsdhandbook.com/pf/cheat_sheet/).

I don't really have experience on it, but the idea would be to:

1 - Create a pfctl rules configuration file:

```
echo "pass in on <docker-interface> proto tcp from any" > /etc/pfrules.tmp
echo "pass out on <docker-interface> proto tcp from any" >> /etc/pfrules.tmp
```

2 - Check and verify the rules

```
pfctl -n -f /etc/pfrules.tmp
```

3 - Load the rules configuation file

```
pfctl -f /etc/pfrules.tmp
```

4 - Enable packet filtering

```
pfctl -e
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your help :) 
there was a small syntax error in both lines `... proto tcp from any`